# Как создать почту webmaster@[наименование].com?

Tags: email, dns

Нужна почта типа `webmaster@[наименование].com` или `hostmaster@[наименование].com`. Но не пойму, как создать.

Comment: 1 - купить домен и хостинг. 2 - зайти в панель управления хостингом/сервером и создать почтовый ящик.

Comment: **1.** Приобретите доменное имя `[наименование].com` // **2** Зарегистрируйте почту `webmaster@[наименование].com`. Возможность кастомной почты предоставляют, например, Яндекс, Мэйл.ру, Yahoo, лично я порекомендовал бы [**Zoho**](https://kb.mailerlite.com/how-to-create-a-free-custom-email-for-your-domain-with-zoho/). // **3.** В панели управления Вашим доменом необходимо добавить MX-записи. Получится примерно так, как на [**этой картинке**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lVYZ5.jpg), процесс отличается в зависимости от хостинга.

Comment: Общую инструкцию по добавлению MX-записей и примеры для некоторых хостинг-провайдеров см. [**здесь**](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/mx.xml). На сайте, где Вы регистрировали домен, должна быть инструкция именно для Вашего провайдера; если не получится справиться с MX-записями самому, техподдержка должна помочь. Спасибо.

Comment: Общий процесс кратко расписал. Если где-то застрянете, задавайте более конкретные вопросы.

Расписал бы более подробно, но, к сожалению, часто, пока пишу длинные ответы, вопросы закрывают.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

### Приобретение места на хостинге и доменного имени

Покупаете или получаете бесплатно, — например, на [**Bitbucket**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html) или [**GitHub Pages**](https://pages.github.com/), если сайт статический, — место на хостинге. Обычно хостеры предоставляют в бесплатное пользование домены третьего уровня, а вот за регистрацию домена второго уровня придётся заплатить, предварительно проверив, не забит ли он уже. Домены второго уровня можно бесплатно получить на [**Freenom**](http://www.freenom.com/ru/index.html?lang=ru), но не в необходимой для Вас зоне `.com,`.

Итак, есть место на хостинге и доменное имя `$имя вашего сайта.com`. Теперь можно создать почтовый аккаунт `$что угодно@$имя вашего сайта.com`. Почтой `$что угодно@$имя сайта, на которое у Вас нет прав.com` пользоваться не получится.

---

---

### Выбор почтовой службы для домена

Раздел основан на субъективном мнении. Рассказывается, какой вариант считает наиболее предпочтительным автор ответа. Это работает.

---

Услугу подключения почты для домена предоставляют некоторые хостеры. Но функционал управления почтовым ящиком может показаться довольно ограниченным. В связи с этим я решил подключить почту для домена на одном из сервисов, предоставляющем эту услугу. Управление почтовым ящиком `$что угодно@$мой домен.com` не будет ничем отличаться от управления ящиком `$что угодно@zoho.com`.

Пользование обычной, не корпоративной почтой, на некоторых сервисах оставило у меня негативные впечатления.

- GMail часто кидал в спам важные письма. Более того, в их спам-листах [**целые почтовые службы**](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail-ru/ydfMTF7IUec/ftliv03hFAAJ). И услуга подключения почты для домена у Google платная.
- Письма с ящиков от Mail.ru нередко не отправляются или попадают в спам.
- Rambler слабо фильтрует спам. Если Ваш адрес включили в спам-рассылку, лучше о нём забыть и создать новый почтовый аккаунт и не на Рамблере.

В итоге остановился на [**бесплатном тарифном плане**](https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html) [**Zoho**](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/email-hosting-with-zoho.html). Каких-то существенных проблем за долгое время пользования не возникало.

---

---

### Создание на Zoho почты для домена

Процесс подробно расписан в статье

- [**How to create a free custom email for your domain with Zoho**](https://kb.mailerlite.com/how-to-create-a-free-custom-email-for-your-domain-with-zoho/)

Переходите на страницу [**Zoho Mail**](https://www.zoho.com/mail/) → `Business Email` → `CONTINUE` → `SELECT FREE PLAN` → заполняете формы → завершаете регистрацию → подтверждаете владение доменом, — на мой взгляд для подтверждения легче создать отдельную HTML-страницу на своём сайте, чем воспользоваться CNAME-методом, описанным в статье.

---

---

### MX-записи

После приобретения доменного имени необходимо заполнить записи DNS в панели управления доменом.

- [**Что такое DNS, принципы работы DNS и почему домены начинают работать не сразу**](https://www.reg.ru/support/domains/dns_servery_i_nastroika_zony/DNS-servery/printsipy-raboty-dns-i-pochemu-domeny-nachinayut-rabotat-ne-srazu)
- [**Что такое «Ресурсные записи DNS»**](https://www.reg.ru/support/domains/dns_servery_i_nastroika_zony/Nastroika-zony/chto-takoe-resursnye-zapisi-dns)

За подключение почты к домену требуется правильно настроить MX-записи. Правильно настройте их в панели управления доменом (не путайтесь в панелях управления, связанных с Вашим сайтом). У меня получилось вот так:

[image: MX-записи]

Для различных хостинг-провайдеров настройки отличаются.

- [**Общая инструкция по настройке MX-записи и инструкции по настройке MX-записи у некоторых хостинг-провайдеров**](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/mx.xml)

На сайте, где приобретён домен, должна быть размещена информация, как настроить MX-записи конкретно в Вашем случае. Пробуете настраивать → отправляете/принимаете тестовые письма с нового ящика `$что угодно@$имя вашего сайта.com`. Не получается — пишите в техподдержку компании, предоставляющей услуги доменного имени, указав, какие действия Вы предприняли. Если техподдержка долго не отвечает — лучше перенести домен на обслуживание к другой компании, не то в будущем понесёте убытки.

---

---

Попытался не забыть нюансы, что отнюдь не исключает факта того, что у Вас может где-нибудь возникнуть загвоздка. Если застрянете на каком-нибудь моменте, предварительно погуглив, задавайте на Stack Overflow уже более конкретный новый вопрос по Вашей загвоздке.